# How to set columns width in a Dynamic Gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How to set columns width in a Dynamic Gridview? When AutoGenerateColumns="true"

Comment: @Ameer: Did you tried [Something from here](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource69-Set-Gridview-column-width-dynamically-using-C.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make changes to RowDataBound event of gridview like this

```
  protected void gvData_RowDataBound(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) {
       e.Row.Cells(0).Width = new Unit("200px");
       e.Row.Cells(1).Width = new Unit("500px");
   }
  }
```

Your markup

```
 <asp:GridView id="gvData" runat="server"                 
              OnRowDataBound="gvData_RowDataBound">
 </asp:GridView>
```

By default autogeneratecolumn is false so no need to specify autogeneratecolumn="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `serverside` method as below:

```
private void GV_RowDataBound(object o, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{        
   // apply custom formatting to data cells
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {
       // set formatting for the category cell
       TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
       cell.Width = new Unit("120px");
       cell.Style["border-right"] = "2px solid #666666";

       // set formatting for value cells
       for(int i=1; i<e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
       {
            cell = e.Row.Cells[i];
            // right-align each of the column cells after the first
            // and set the width
            cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
            cell.Width = new Unit("90px");
            // alternate background colors
            if (i % 2 == 1)
                  cell.BackColor 
                      =  System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#EFEFEF");
                  // check value columns for a high enough value
                  // (value >= 8000) and apply special highlighting
            }                    
        }

        // apply custom formatting to the header cells
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                cell.Style["border-bottom"] = "2px solid #666666";
                cell.BackColor=System.Drawing.Color.LightGray;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Your `aspx` page

```
<asp:GridView id="myList" runat="server"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="true"
                  OnRowDataBound="GV_RowDataBound"
                  . . . 
                  >
</asp:GridView>
```

For detailed information you can check **[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15988/Formatting-AutoGenerateColumns-in-an-ASP-NET-Grid)**

Comment: by default  AutoGenerateColumns is "true" .So it's useless to mention

Comment: I agree, but I think you need to check your answer too as you have mentioned _By default autogeneratecolumn is **false** so no need to specify autogeneratecolumn="true"_ :)